# Showing active users between dates in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

My data has users along with their start and end date.
I would like to create a time series chart, showing how the number changes over time. For each day, it should show the total count of users where the date on the chart falls between that users start/end date.

Adding the start or end dates to the chart didn't yield desired results.
The closest I can get is by creating a calculated field Current_date(), and then placing that in both Date Range Dimension and Dimension fields. Metric is Record Count.

This shows a running date (for example last 7 days or whatever I set), but everything is 0 except for the last chart point (current date) which shows the correct number.
I tried creating a calculated field with if startdate<=current_date and enddate>= current_date but I obviously couldn't get it quite right.

Completely new to Looker Studio so if there's something simple I'm missing mea culpa.